# Dataframe date conversion of different types

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing into a df from Excel, and the result of the date column resembles something like this dummy df, where some dates are yyyy-mm-dd-like, and others are codes.

```
data = ['2020-01-20 00:00:00', '2020-04-27 00:00:00', '43836']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['entry_date'])
```

```
            entry_date
0  2020-01-20 00:00:00
1  2020-04-27 00:00:00
2                43836
```

I have tried doing one conversion with `errors='ignore'`, and then the next. It does not seem to like that, when the conversion of the code-like date comes, it is complaining about the format

`df['entry_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['entry_date'], unit='D', origin='1899-12-30')` gives me the following error:

```
Name: entry_date, Length: 292334, dtype: object' is not compatible with origin='1899-12-30'; it must be numeric with a unit specified
```

How can I write one statement that will handle both of the conversions?

Comment: I only see now that the above is a series and not a dataframe, but either way, I am still struggling to do both converts without making an intermediate dataframe.

Comment: Hi, you mention *both conversions*, but only show one. How should `43836` be converted?

Comment: Hi @Laurent, because '2019-11-18' and '43836' exist in the same dataframe the are stored as objects. I then use ```pd.to_datetime(df['entry_date'], errors='coerce')``` for the 2019-11-18'. The second conversion is on the '43836', and for that I use ```pd.to_datetime(df['entry_date'], unit='D', origin='1899-12-30')```, but can only do so after converting it to numeric using ```pd.to_numeric(df['entry_date'], errors='coerce')```  So I can get all this to work if I split it off into intermediate dateframes, but I would like to keep it as one

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df = df.apply(
    lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x["entry_date"], errors="coerce")
    if pd.to_datetime(x["entry_date"], errors="coerce") is not pd.NaT
    else pd.to_datetime(
        pd.to_numeric(x["entry_date"], errors="coerce"),
        unit="D",
        origin="1899-12-30",
    ),
    axis=1,
)
```

Then:

```
# Output
0   2020-01-20
1   2020-04-27
2   2020-01-06
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```